# delphi -> sql server query returns empty string but with correct length

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, localdb

I have a Delphi program that connects to a sql server database hosted via LocalDB. In this program, I need to run the below query and get the contents of the "Value" field. When I run the query in SQL server, it returns "127.0.0.1" as expected. However, when I run the query from Delphi, it returns a string with the correct length, but mostly null data. In the case of the IP address, it (roughly) returns "#0#0#0#0''#0#0". What is more strange is the Key returns the correct value (defined in sql as nvarchar(128), not null) whereas the Value does not (defined in sql as nvarchar(MAX), null).

Here's my connection string (if relevant): Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=TestDb;Uid=dba;Pwd=sql;

[image: SQL and query results]

[image: Delphi code and query results]

Comment: Try to convert Value in the query to nvarchar(100) so that it isn't nvarchar(MAX)

Comment: That did it. If you want to move this comment to the answer, I'll mark it answered.

Comment: Libraries like FireDAC should handle that. Hard to say which client library do you use.

Comment: Indeed, what library are you using? The ones built-in to Delphi (ADO and FireDAC) work just fine.

Comment: I'm using ADO for database access

Comment: I use ADO all the time, and never faced such an issue.